# Filtrado incorrecto en una Conlsulta MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Que tal, estoy desarrollando un sistema en donde tengo un filtro de la base de datos.

Tengo la base de datos con un campo llamado "estado" en donde almaceno 4 diferentes datos que son (Pendiente, Activo, Concluido, No Procede)

otros llamados "depto1" y otro llamado "depto2" en donde almaceno los diferentes tipos de Jefaturas que existen en la empresa

Necesito filtrar los datos en donde muestre todos los campos iguales a el "estado" que se encuentran en "depto1 o depto2"

Esta es mi consulta:
Pero se esta mezclando un dato erróneo que no equivale a la variable "estado"

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM solicitudes 
          WHERE estado = '$filtro' 
                and depto1 = '".$usu."' 
                OR depto2 = '".$usu."' 
          ORDER BY folio DESC";
```

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola lo que esta pasando, es que tienes que agrupar el **OR** dentro de parentisis,  para que tu **WHERE** te quede:   estado y los dos departamentos. Aquí te paso el código:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM solicitudes WHERE estado = '".$filtro."' AND (depto1 = '".$usu."' OR depto2 = '".$usu."') ORDER BY folio DESC"
```

Comment: Tan sinple y sencillo como esto

Comment: Perfecto.. Muchas Gracias!